# Cannot open Colab Notebook in my Google Drive

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

When I try to open a Colab Notebook (ipynb file) in my Google Drive I get an error:

> Notebook loading error
> There was an error loading this notebook. Ensure that the file is accessible and try again.
> Failed to fetch

I get this error on any Colab Notebook created today or yesterday, and I get the same error if I try to open a new Notebook in Colab.  But I don’t get the error if I open a Colab Notebook that was created before yesterday (they open OK).

Comment: Can you check the [Chrome developer console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) and include any errors you observe there? Does this behavior reproduce in an incognito window?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and relocating the files didn't help.
The solution that worked for me is to:

1. disable ALL your adblocks
2. also disable service intercepting your trafic, like the disconnect.me chrome extension (tells you if you are being tracked and who tracks you)

Comment: You, sir, saved me. I've been trying everything to fix Colab's sudden odd behaviours and this seems to have worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the options suggested here didn't work,

so I did the following:

1. go to google drive
2. click on the gear icon > settings
3. go to manage apps > look for google colaboratory
4. Check use by default
5. click on DONE

that's it.

Answer (score 1):

The same. From Android device, on Google Drive, .ipynb files were associated as a bin files.
Possible upshot (valid for me...) is copy to default "Colab Notebooks" folder and open from browser when https://colab.research.google.com opens the wizard.
[image: Select from defauld colab folder]

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue 
fixed it by disabling the vpn | adblock

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug , but google solved it.But if happens again, you can try incognito mode with all extensions disabled

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29854642)